# Manipulating Array After Pulling From Text File

Tags: arrays, vb.net, listbox

I've been thoroughly combing StackOverflow and other sources for the answers to these problems, and have not been able to find a solution that would work cohesively with the steps I need to accomplish.

Things I need to do:

1. Create an array from a text file and display in a listbox **(this is done and works)**
2. Have user fill in a text box, click a button, and the array is searched for anything matching the text box's value
3. Have the results of the search displayed in a separate listbox

Here's what I've got so far, and it's fairly hacked together, so if there's anything that can be improved, naturally, I'd be all for that.
`

```
Public Class Form1

Dim lblName As Object
Public colleges As String
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim colleges() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Colleges.txt")
    ListBoxCollege.Items.AddRange(colleges)
End Sub

Private Sub btnSearchGo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearchGo.Click
    Dim n As Integer, college As String
    college = txtCollegeSearchUserInput.Text
    n = Array.IndexOf(colleges(), college)
    If n <> 1 Then
        [[Needs to output into new listbox, preferably here]]
    End If
End Sub
```

If there's anything else needed from VB, I can provide if necessary!

Comment: (this does not seem to me as a good way to learn programming) IndexOf can only deal with one match (the first one); BTW the condition should be If n <> -1 Then. If you are expecting various matches you should rely on a different approach. For example: a loop or a LINQ method (e.g., Where). You can put all these results in another array and populate the ListBox with it. But you should do some basic reading and step-by-step learning; this approach of  asking each bit is very bad for you and, in any case, not too SO-compatible (you might get a comment like this one or be most likely ignored).

Comment: you have a lot of different `college` variables.  `Public colleges` is a form level one, `Dim colleges()` is a different one that only exists in form load, and another `college As String` in the click event.  None of them are the same.  Then there is another `colleges()` that pops up in the click event.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can do something like this

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ListBoxCollege.Items.Count -1

    If ListBoxCollege.Items(i).ToString().IndexOf(college, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1 Then
        findList.Items.Add(ListBoxCollege.Items(i))
    End If

Next
```

The difference here - you calling `IndexOf` on array and I call it for each item in list. Therefore I return all matches, while you only the first one

This is little bit limited in search criteria. You could use regex as well for wild cards etc. Or you store your data (colleges) in `System.Data.DataTable`, and you would be able to run Sql `Select` queries on it almost like in database.